# How to select element with single class name in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below html and want to get the element based on 'natural' class. The reason is I get t dynamic classes after 'natural'

```
 <coral-checkbox class="natural coral-Form-field coral3-Checkbox" ></coral-checkbox>
```

I am trying below code to get hide the element but it is not working.

```
$("coral-checkbox[class='.natural']").hide();
```

But it is working when I select entire class like below but I need to do with only 'natural'. Is this possible ?

```
$("coral-checkbox[class='.natural coral-Form-field coral3-Checkbox']").hide();
```

Comment: That second version shouldn't work, either, because you have `.` before `natural`.

Comment: No, it is not working even without . dot

Comment: I know, that's not the only problem. But you claimed that the second version works, and it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.classname` to select based on any of the element's classed. When you use an attribute selector, it matches the entire attribute (unless you use modifiers like `*=`, but they're not appropriate here, either).

```
$("coral-checkbox.natural").hide();
```

Comment: Beat me by 15 secs :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the class the selector instead of the attribute selector:

```
$("coral-checkbox.natural").hide();
```

Comment: @ezhil, you should accept Barmar's answer cuz it came first.